# Gradle artifacts declaration

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I need some guidance and clarification about how artifacts are declared in gradle tasks, I would like to upload files to maven/artifactory reading these files from any kind of output container instead of having to hardcode the path for each artifact generated.

This is simpler if you have a JAR, ZIP, File, and a few other types, because you can make use of project.artifacts.add(...), but this is not trivial when you have some random file types.

Im going to provide an example to specify and clarify what I need exactly:

if I have:

```
task generateMyFile {
  doLast {
    buildDir.mkdirs()
    ['touch', new File(buildDir, 'myfile.random').absolutePath].execute().waitFor()
  }
}
```

- What's the right way to declare *myfile.random* as the output for *generateMyFile* ?
- How do I declare *myfile.random* to be a valid artifact that will be used by maven/artifactory later by the 'publish' task ? currently I assume the file was generated in build/myfile.random, but Im looking for a smarter solution, and gradle documentation (or any other source) is not clear about this.

Thanks in advance